# Similar (Simple) Formulas Producing Entirely Different Results

Tags: excel, formula, equals

Ok so the issue is a spreadsheet where the goal is to check if two columns end up equaling the same. One column has the 'goal result' and the other column is usually a formula. (A starting number, plus a number of changes that haven't yet been issued in the paperwork, should equal the 'goal result.)

There's a third 'check column' that will display either `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether the two have equal values.

Now the issue is that sometimes, for no reason I can discern at all, the 'check column' will display `FALSE` even though the result values are clearly the same. There's no change in format, no difference in cell structure or formula structure. I appreciate that one shows a formula and one doesn't but my spreadsheet it massive, hundreds of rows, so there's no reason this should only be an issue in 1/50 or so cells.

A snippet example

[image]

An example of the formula in the working (top) row.

[image]

An example of the formula in the row working differently

[image]

The forumla that generates the `TRUE` or `FALSE` is as simple as "=H=I" (With the cell numbers obviously.)

EDIT: Thanks for the great response guys. The rounding solution worked. There was only addition and the true value IS only two decimals so I still don't quite understand why that would be an issue but I've replaced the formula throughout the sheet anyway, to be safe. Thanks again!

Comment: Probably rounding error - use ROUND to an acceptable amount of decimals when you check that they are equal.

Comment: This has to do with rounding, what you see is not what Excel sees.  Round the output to check: `=ROUND(H2,2)=ROUND(I2,2)`